# printf ptr: can the leading 0x be eliminated?

Tags: linux, printf

The Linux printf renders %p arguments as hex digits with a leading 0x. Is there a way to make it not print the 0x? (Needs to work on both 32 and 64 bit.)

Comment: Try %x in place of %p... Well, %x is for unsigned int and %p for pointers...

Comment: That will fail on 64 bit, won't it?

Comment: Yes, it will. Does "%llx." exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the format specifier for `uintptr_t` from `<inttypes.h>`:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
[...]
printf("%"PRIxPTR"\n", (uintptr_t) p);
```

This works like `%x` for the `uintptr_t` type, which is an integer type capable of roundtrip conversion from/to any pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

Use %llx, it will work on 64-bit for sure. Tried and tested.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%lx` or `%08lx`. It works for both 32 and 64 bit linux gcc, because `long int` is always the same width as `void *`. Doesn't work for MSVC, because `long int` is always 32 bit in MSVC.

If you want it to work on all compilers, you can use `%llx` and cast your pointer to `unsigned long long int`, it's not efficient in 32 bit though.

If you want efficiency as well, define different macro for different cases.