# Why is the format of %p and %x different in a format string?

Tags: c, printf, format-string

When printing a hexadecimal value (`%x`) and an address (`%p`), the format is slightly different. The printed value does not start with `0x` in the case of a hexadecimal value:

```
int main()
{
     int x = 0x1234;
     printf("Value of x: %x\n", x);
     printf("Address of x: %p\n", (void*)&x);
}
```

yields (gcc):

```
Value of x: 1234
Address of x: 0xffb0fbfc
```

Why is the `0x` forced on you in the case of an address?

I guess it boils down to the standard.

What would be the correct way to print an address without the `0x` if i wanted to? The `%p` is not only a `%x` with an added `0x` right?

Comment: you might take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6040763/2082964

Comment: Note that you should be passing an `unsigned int` to `printf` for `%x`, for instance by declaring `x` of this type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> p
>
> The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printable characters, **in an
>   implementation-defined manner**.

[reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html)

Answer (score 5):

The output format for `%p` is implementation specific. Not every C implementation is on machines with addresses of the same size as `int`. There is the `intptr_t` from `<stdint.h>`

Answer (score 3):

> The %p is not only a %x with an added 0x right?

No.. `%p` expects the argument to be of type (void *) and prints out the address.

Whereas `%x` converts an unsigned int to unsigned hexadecimal and prints out the result.

And coming to what `%p` does is implementation defined but the standard just says that `%p` expects `void*` argument else the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

MSVC does not force the "0x" prefix on me, but you could optionally remove it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 123;
    char hexstr[20];
    sprintf(hexstr,"%p", (void*)&x);
    if (strstr(hexstr,"0x") == hexstr)
        printf ("%s\n", hexstr+2);
    else
        printf ("%s\n", hexstr);
    return 0;
}
```